# The value of one input is affecting another

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, input

I have a simple app which allows someone to add a numbers into an input, and have those numbers render onto the page (as inputs) which can be edited.

```
  addSiblingValue(evt) {
    this.setState({
      currentObject: {
        ...this.state.currentObject,
        numberOfSiblings: evt.target.value
      }
    });

  add() {
    const array = [...this.state.array, this.state.currentObject];
    this.setState({
      array
    });
  }

  siblingCountChange(rowIndex, event) {
    const array = [...this.state.array];
    array[rowIndex].numberOfSiblings = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ array });
  }
```

So when I add a number it renders a new input with the value set to the number I've just added, but when I go to change that value, it now is affecting the first input.

The first row of inputs are using their own object `currentObject` which pushes to to the `this.state.array`, so I'm not sure why editing anything in that array would affect the `currentObject`?

Expected behaviour:

1. User enters a number into the input and clicks add
2. That input is rendered and can be edited independently

How do I achieve this or what is it I'm doing wrong here?

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/0nzyy35kv)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you add `this.state.currentObject` to the array, it works as an reference, so that the added object in the array and `this.state.currentObject` are the same object. You can prevent that by adding not the object itself, but a copy of the object into the array:

```
  add() {
    const array = [...this.state.array, {"numberOfSiblings": this.state.currentObject.numberOfSiblings}];
    this.setState({
      array
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    siblingCountChange(rowIndex, event) {
    const array = [...this.state.array];
    array[rowIndex].numberOfSiblings += parseInt(event.target.value);
    this.setState({ array });
  }
```

You were not adding the actual number to the current state. I also removed the value from the add like so:

```
<input
 type="text"
 onChange={this.siblingCountChange.bind(this, rowIndex)}
/>
```

You will need to put error handling on the state as a string plus a number leads to NaN error. As you can see the number is parsed before addition.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to dieckie for pointing me in the right direction. Unfortunately that particular solution did not work, but using [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to create a reference and pushing that to the array did?

Posting here so it helps others/myself in future:

```
  add() {
    let copyOfCurrentObject = Object.assign({}, this.state.currentObject);
    const array = [...this.state.array, copyOfCurrentObject];
    this.setState({
      array
    })
  }
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510063/javascript-object-reference-linked-to-object-in-array) question was also helpful.